# How to do basic WATCH with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I would like to do a basic watch with StackExchange.Redis. Where if a key is changed during the transaction, it fails.

StackExchange.Redis has abstracted this nicely to a "Condition" api, which supports concepts of "Equals" and "Exists".

That's really nice, but I would like to just do something like "Unchanged". I might be missing something, but it's not obvious to me at this point on how to do that.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
var transaction = redis.CreateTransaction();
transaction.AddCondition(Condition.StringUnchanged("key")); //the API here could maybe be simplified
var val = transaction.StringGet("key"); //notably, this is not async because you would have to get the result immediately - it would only work on watched keys
transaction.StringSetAsync("key", val + 1);
transaction.Execute();
```

Or even a possible better version (which would do the same thing):

```
var transaction = redis.CreateTransaction();
var val = transaction.Watch("key"); //this would return the value!
transaction.StringSetAsync("key", val + 1);
transaction.Execute();
```

Currently the only way I understand of doing this would be to do something along the lines of:

```
var val = redis.StringGet("key");
var transaction = redis.CreateTransaction();
transaction.AddCondition(Condition.StringEqual("key", val));
transaction.StringSetAsync("key", val + 1);
transaction.Execute();
```

Which from an attempt at reading the SE.Redis code I understand to translate to something like (not sure how accurate this is):

```
val = GET key
WATCH key
MULTI
val = val + 1
SET key $val
checkVal = GET key
(then if checkVal != val:) UNWATCH
(otherwise:) EXEC
```

I'm still learning more about Redis, but I'm not quite sure what the benefit of this is. Wouldn't you rather the end result be something more like this?:

```
WATCH key
MULTI
val = GET key
val = val + 1
SET key $val
EXEC
```

Or is this not possible with the way SE.Redis works?

Comment: I will edit my answer to reflect your edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `WATCH` isn't exposed directly is because of how SE.Redis is designed to multiplex commands from different call stacks on a single connection. This makes it necessary for any transaction work to be *very* tightly managed.

I am unclear of quite what the purpose of "unchanged" would be *by itself*, without comparison to some known value - otherwise you're just creating a race condition. It would definitely be possible to add support for it, but I'd really like to understand the expected use-case first. Can you explain?

---

Re your edit; your preferred example (the last one) simply isn't possible *with redis* - nothing to do with SE.Redis; if you do a `GET` inside a `MULTI`, you don't get the answer until the `EXEC` completes - so you can't possibly use the value in the `SET`: *it isn't available yet*.

If it wasn't for multiplexing, you could re-order your second example (based on what SE.Redis does) a bit:

```
WATCH key
val = GET key
MULTI
val = val + 1
SET key $val
EXEC
```

this is the *typical* use of `WATCH`: you *watch* the things that you're querying in advance, then you know that `{key}` is unchanged during this loop (or at least, the transaction will have aborted; no inconsistent state). However, `WATCH` *does not play well with a multiplexer*, which is why SE.Redis forces you down the route of fetching the value *in advance of the transaction*, then allowing you to compare the value to assert that it is unchanged. Same result; slightly different approach, but it is multiplexer-safe. For more on that topic [see here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated the question to hopefully explain it better.

Comment: Ok, very very helpful. The two keys there I was missing was 1: you have to get the `WATCH`ed value before the `MULTI`, or it doesn't work. 2: because of the multiplexer, the concept of 'unchanged' doesn't really work - you need something to compare to. Good to know.

Comment: On another note - SE.Redis is an awesome library to work with, thanks for all your work on it.

Comment: @Ben it perhaps goes without saying that `val = INCR key` would be the right way to do this example. For more complicated examples, you might want to consider `EVAL` / `EVALSHA`

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you so much. Unfortunately that article still does not explain how to achieve the effect of simple watch-multi-exec transaction in SE.Redis. It tells about conditions, but I do not need them, I need to abort transaction if the key has changed -- just as raw WATCH command does. I am wondering... Can I use a condition which is always true for that?